# JS-Interop : Attempting to use salesforce proxy

Tags: dart

I'm trying to use Salesforce's sforce library to place an Ajax call to salesforce. Here is the example javascript that is working:

```js
function setupPage() {

    var state = { //state that you need when the callback is called
        output : document.getElementById("output"),
        startTime : new Date().getTime()};

    var callback = {
        //call layoutResult if the request is successful
        onSuccess: layoutResults,
        //call queryFailed if the api request fails
        onFailure: queryFailed,
        source: state};

    sforce.connection.query(
            "Select Id, Name, Industry From Account order by Industry",
            callback);
}
function queryFailed(error, source) {
    // not shown function code
}

function layoutResults(queryResult, source) {
   // not shown function code
}
```

Here's my dart implementation:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
import 'dart:json';

void main() {

  js.scoped(() {

    var sforce = js.context.sforce;

    var callbackSuccess = new js.Callback.once(success);
    var callbackFailed = new js.Callback.once(failure);

    var sfdc = new js.Proxy(sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Name, Industry From Account order by Industry"),
        js.map({"onSuccess" : callbackSuccess, "onFailure" : callbackFailed}));    

  });
}

void success(queryResult) {
  print("queryResult is: " + queryResult);
}

void failure(error) {
  print("error is: " + error);
}
```

The Ajax call is being placed, as I see the POST request being made and returning data. However, I always seem to get this error (and I've tried countless different combinations):

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function (program):370
construct (program):370
ReceivePortSync.dispatchCall darttest:178
$$._JsSendPortSync.callSync$1 minidartjs:4929
$.Proxy_Proxy$withArgList minidartjs:8194
$.Proxy_Proxy minidartjs:8183
$$.main_anon.call$0 minidartjs:6057
$.scoped minidartjs:8136
$.main minidartjs:8066
$$._IsolateContext.eval$1 minidartjs:276
$.startRootIsolate minidartjs:6533
(anonymous function)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm not sure where to turn at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because you try to create a `js.Proxy` (`sfdc`) with the result of `sforce.connection.query(...)` . When you use `new js.Proxy(f)`, `f` must be a `js.Proxy` of a js `function`. Here you get an `object` and that's why you get the error.

Here's the code that should work.

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
import 'dart:json';

void main() {

  js.scoped(() {

    var sforce = js.context.sforce;

    var callbackSuccess = new js.Callback.once(success);
    var callbackFailed = new js.Callback.once(failure);

    sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Name, Industry From Account order by Industry",
        js.map({"onSuccess" : callbackSuccess, "onFailure" : callbackFailed}));

  });
}

void success(queryResult, source) {
  print("queryResult is: " + queryResult);
}

void failure(error, source) {
  print("error is: " + error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip -- that helped in getting further. However, when I run it using the above, it results in a:

Uncaught NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'call$2'
Receiver: Instance of 'Function'
Arguments: ["NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'call$2'\nReceiver: Instance of 'Function'\nArguments: [Instance of 'Proxy', null]", null] 

If I add the optional source variable to the map with a null value, the error callback is invoked, but a different error occurs ("Illegal argument(s): Instance of 'Proxy' ").

Comment: You get this error because of [issue 9283](http://dartbug.com/9283). TL;DR avoid `--minify` option of *dart2js* until it is fixed.

Comment: The code isn't minified -- it's confusing because I name the page mini.dart (based on the tutorial). When I look at the code, it's very human-readable. I'll try running in dartium.

Comment: ok, I read too quickly ! The error is because the `success` is not defined with the good number of parameter. It should be `void success(queryResult, source)`. I will update the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. I still receive the "Uncaught NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'call$2'" error. I think I've exhausted all of the combinations I can think of and will instead try going in a different direction.